# Is it possible to set Compatibility mode in Iframe for IE browsers

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, microsoft-edge, x-ua-compatible

I have created Data visualization application in angular2 and another application is in traditional asp.net application.In the asp.net application is using Iframe for Angular application data visualisation.In asp.net application using lots of feature support for IE8 browsers and so used below tag  in asp.net application.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

But angular 2 data visualisation is not working on asp.net application,because which uses IE8 mode,

Sample Example:

asp.net application with angular2 iframe

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> 
<title>Asp.net App</title>

</script>
>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;">
        <iframe  width="450" height="400" src="angular2urldataVisualization"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**

- Asp.net uses lots of functionality support for IE8.So don't want to
  change the IE8 mode .
- In angular4 app, I have set the meta   http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
       content="IE=edge"

which is not loaded    because of asp.net uses
   strict iE8 mode. In this case , how to solve the issue

Comment: iframes inherit the documentMode (document.documentMode) of the parent web page in IE11. A workaround is to use a popup window with a hyperlink eg. <a href="angular2urldataVisualization" target="_blank">visualization</a>....you should be using Enterprise Site Mode lists I/o x-ua meta tags to manage your backward compatibility of legacy intranet apps.

Comment: you could try an object tag instead... eg. <object type="text/html:charset=utf-8" data="angular2urldataVisualization"></object>

Comment: In your content forms you could set the x-ua meta to a higher emulation mode, so that your legacy intranet application can support modern/standard features while using IE 11.

Comment: Did you find a work-around? Anyone?